# How to install NOOB's onto SDcard on Chromebook

Tags: linux, noobs

I only have a chromebook. I have a RaspPie 3 B. I want to install NOOB's onto it. There is this guide [here](http://analphabetoftech.blogspot.co.nz/2016/05/how-to-prepare-raspberry-pi-sd-card-on.html) but it shows how to install an .img.

**Is there a way I can convert my NOOB's folder downloaded from** [here:](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_latest) (don't click it or it'll start downloading 2gb worth!) **to an .img so I can follow the guide I linked?**

Or will I have to do a full build, ie. *(If you're comfortable enough, you can just simply download the operating system ISO, format the SD card, mount the ISO, and boot the Pi. )*

Comment: I know nothing about Chromebooks, and if I were you I wouldn't follow some random link - use the Foundation [guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/software-guide/quickstart/). `NOOBS` is **NOT** installed from an image - just unzip the file, and copy to your SD Card.

Comment: This is off-topic, since it's about how to create bootable USB/SD on a chromeOS device. check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/278403/how-do-you-make-usb-bootable-on-chromebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide you are using is probably outdated. Here is the right way.

**Step 1:** Follow [this guide](http://www.omgchrome.com/format-sd-card-usb-chromebook/) to format your SD card.

**Step 2:** Download [NOOBS from it's official site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/).

**Step 3:** Extract the ZIP.

**Step 4:** Copy the contents of the extracted zip to the SD card but not the folder itself.

That's really it. Your SD card should work with your Raspberry Pi now.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, none of the above work to install NOOBS from a Chromebook because when formatting the SD card, no MBR partition is created and the Pi simply displays "Cannot find the drive with NOOBS files" [More info](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues/498)

Here's what I did to install Raspbian using my Chromebook:

1. Format the SD card using the Chromebook file browser
2. Download the latest Raspbian zip file
3. Open Chromebook recovery utility
4. Select the SD card - DO NOT ERASE it
5. Select the gear icon and choose the Raspbian zip file to copy

Answer (score 1):

I just did it with the Chromebook Recovery Utility earlier today. It formats the card for you as well.

I should have figured it was an option sooner, as the whole purpose of the application is to flash a ChromeOS image to restore your machine, but I didn't find a single website that suggested it.

Click the settings icon for those options, the process is pretty straightforward, so you can tell what you'll be writing to.

I haven't had a chance to do anything much past booting it up for the first time and changing some settings, but using dd in a root shell kept giving me a kernel panic error at boot.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I was also having trouble with just dragging NOOBS onto the card from the zip file; it never booted after more than ten minutes, and the activity LED was looping in a pattern. I used the zipped desktop image with the recovery utility.